# Ghostscript / GhostPDF print several pages into one PDF

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, ghostscript

I need to print several times different pages and gather them into a final resulting PDF. I have had this setup and configuration on a company laptop a few years ago but I can't get it to work now on my workstation.

The configuration allowed me to do this in a very simple way, it was only a normal print dialog and a button which allowed me to "Save documents in printer spool to PDF".

How can I configure Ghostscript / GhostPDF to do that?

If you have a solution that uses a different free tool that works for me, this would also be fine.

Willing to reward 200 bounty for a working answer.

Comment: I use PDFTKBuilder to combine or aplit PDFs. Works great. http://download.cnet.com/PDFTK-Builder/3000-18497_4-198814.html

Comment: I use Print&Share with Profile option: "Documents are combined into one transmission". but that is not a free tool...